# how to return all but one column of a 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

My `y` variable `PRICE` is a column in the middle of a NumPy array, its position is stored in `y_idx`. I want my `x` variables to be all of the columns in the array except for the one in `y_idx`'s location.

In R I would use a negative sign to drop a column from a selection like this:

```
# specify x and y variables
y_idx = df.columns.get_loc('PRICE')
y = dataset[:,y_idx]
x = dataset[:,-y_idx]
```

How can I set `x` to all columns in the array except for the one that `y` is set to?

Comment: If you can expand on the example snippet a bit and include an example array it will make it easier to help you out with a solution.

Comment: `dataset[:, np.arange(arr.shape[1]) != y_idx]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you might be working with pandas dataFrame. In that case:

```
x= df.drop('PRICE', axis=1)
y = df['PRICE']
```